# How to use browser-sync just for ghost mode

Tags: javascript, browser-sync

I'm using `browserify` and `amok` to hot-reload my project during development. This way I can build my project continuously and get all live changes whenever i edit & save my `html`, `js` or `css` and I serve my project on localhost using the static http server `ecstatic`

I open my website in an `android emulator`, on a usb connected `mobile device` and in several `web browsers`

What I would like to add is the option to "synchronize" the navigation (clicking, scrolling, etc...) the way browser-sync does, without all the other capabilities that come with it.

Is there a stand-alone project, that just does the "ghost mode" feature of browser-sync?
If not, can browser-sync be used in a way that it does just that?